# FInd tweet time of a tweet

Tags: python, tweepy

How can I find tweet time of a tweet using tweepy API ?

```
{"created_at":"Tue Dec 08 15:00:07 +0000 2015","id":674242055254732800,"id_str":"674242055254732800","text":"His twin hundreds in the Delhi Test proved that Ajinkya Rahane is the best Indian Test batsman right now. https:\/\/t.co\/Eow0doIwXu","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.sprinklr.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eSprinklr\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":69506712,"id_str":"69506712","name":"Yahoo India","screen_name":"YahooIndia","location":"World Wide Web","url":"http:\/\/in.yahoo.com\/","description":"Get all the latest news and info from the world of politics, sports, lifestyle, world news, technology and more - all in one place! RTs not endorsements","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":62162,"friends_count":114,"listed_count":761,"favourites_count":95,"statuses_count":23543,"created_at":"Fri Aug 28 04:44:40 +0000 2009","utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"New Delhi","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"400090","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/463624776380985344\/-SJQ19Jf.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/463624776380985344\/-SJQ19Jf.jpeg","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"400090","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000414391041\/57bea548f168229bfa7233f740ad5bda_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000414391041\/57bea548f168229bfa7233f740ad5bda_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/69506712\/1424053546","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/Eow0doIwXu","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/1lqCATI","display_url":"bit.ly\/1lqCATI","indices":[106,129]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1449586807441"}
```

Comment: can you show what you've already tried?

Comment: In the JSON , created_at and timestamp_ms given which is local system time